# Gitlab Jenkins Webhook integration

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, integration, webhooks

So the purpose was to trigger a build on a Jenkins job after making a push to Gitlab Repo, Simple right?

After Downloading Gitlab pluging, setting up the project, still no luck. I get a 403 error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some trial and error here is how I solved the issue:

Things I try:
[Web hook fails when Jenkins Anonymous user does not have job/build permission](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/issues/375)
[Need to document GitLab -> Jenkins authentication setup](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/issues/418)
[How Do You Troubleshoot the GitLab Integration Webhook Error "Permission you need to have (but didn't) hudson.model.Hudson"?](http://continualintegration.com/miscellaneous-articles/how-do-you-troubleshoot-the-gitlab-integration-webhook-error-permission-you-need-to-have-but-didnt-hudsonmodelhudson)

This are the steps that I follow to fix this error

> "Hook executed successfully but returned HTTP 403... You are authenticated as anonymous Groups that you are in: Permission you need to have (but didn't) hudson.model.Hudson.Read...which is implied by hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead..."

Go to **Jenkins>Manage Jenkins>configuration**
go to the Gitlab section and make sure is like so:
[image: Make sure Enable authentication for 'project' end-point is activated]
After setting up all this test your connection and make sure is successfull.

On your Jenkins project go **Configure > Build Triggers** and select
**Build when a change is pushed to Gitlab. Gitlab webhook URL...**
also, make sure to generate the token in advanced settings

[image: remember to generate the token in advanced settings]
Now in Gitlab go to your **Project>Settings>Integrations**
paste the URL you got in your Jenkins project, as well as the token generated in the Gitlab Build Triggers section, remove ssl verification
[image: Webhook conf]

Now hit save and test your hook
[image: Test hook]

you should get 200 success message on Gitlab and on Jenkins a triggered Job:
[image: GitlabSuccess hook]
[image: Jenkins initiated job]
If that's not the case and you still get the 403, This are things you can do:

in Gitlab add a Jenkins user to your project (the one you're trying to get the webhook triggered from). This time it should work!!!
[image: gitlab members]

**Troubleshooting**

If it still not working another helper you can use is to add a logger to Jenkins 
go to  **Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > System log**

- add a new log recorder. Type in the name of the logger
- add the loggers on the input field. Start typing gitlab or webhooks,
  anything related to Gitlab or webhooks :)
  [image: loggers]
  [image: loggers conf]
  hit save and start seeing whats going on when you hit the hook from Gitlab
  [image: logs]

Comment: Go to Manage Jenkins > Configure Global Security and add the Build Element Permission for the anonymous user.

Comment: Very good instructions! On recent GitLab, it's now under: Project Settings --> Webhooks

Comment: Excellent answer. Check "Filter branches by regex"， what does the "Source Branch Regex" and "Target Branch Regex" mean ?